# Spring - Webjar Bootstrap got overriten

Tags: java, html, spring, twitter-bootstrap, thymeleaf

In a spring maven project i have some html pages that uses thymeleaf and bootstrap, they worked perfectly until for whatever reason the `/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7-1/css/bootstrap.min.css` and `/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7-1/js/bootstrap.min.js` that used to be proper bootstrap.css and bootstrap.js got overriten and now they are copies of the pages.

*index.html head*

```
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Title</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u"
      crossorigin="anonymous" th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7-1/css/bootstrap.min.css}">
    <script src="/webjars/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"/>
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa"
        crossorigin="anonymous" th:src="@{/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7-1/js/bootstrap.min.js}"></script>
</head>
```

If i open the page source and click on any of those links they show a copy of the html page instead of .css and .js code. This didn't happen a couple of hours ago, i never touched the maven dependencies so i have no idea how this could have happened, a simple fix is to remove the `th:href` and leave the nomal href to do the job but i would prefer to use the local .css and .js. These are the dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.7-1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```